# CSS Color parent line

Tags: html, css

I am a CSS beginner and I need to colorize a line of an HTML table that contains a cell `<th>` with an specific id

How can I acces parent element of my `th:id=yeah` to add this css option : `background-color:red`

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th id="yeah">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="one">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  #one{
    background-color: red
  }

  tr#yeah{
    background-color: blue
  }

  table.class-name th:first-child {
    background: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Can you please claarify which part of the table you need colorized? the whole head? Because I can see you also you blue in your css

Comment: This table is an extract from a complex table, the point is that I have a th(or td) with a specific id and I need to colorize all the line (so the parent tr). Hope it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

you were so close!

your CSS:

```
tr#yeah{
background-color: blue;
}
```

Change:

```
#yeah{
background-color: blue;
}
```

Little thing to keep in mind.  When styling elements in CSS you don't have to always include the TAG (  )

CSS knows you're styling a specific element by its Tag ID (#yeah) which is why you give your element a ID in html.

Good luck out there :D happy learning.

Comment: Thank you but it only colorize the cell 'Firstname'. I need to colorize all the parent tr with my cells 'Firstname','Lastname' and 'Age'

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a framing problem. What you're asking is how to take an element you've found and do something to its parent.

You can't. CSS doesn't work that way. It doesn't go backwards.

**EDIT: My first 2 suggestions give alternative structures to accomplish what I believe is the end goal. If you absolutely must have the structure you provided then my third answer provides a possible workaround that may or may not actually work depending on your very specific circumstances.**

What you seem to be trying to accomplish in practice is to style the header of your table though, and that's completely possible. It comes down to how you structure your elements and the use of the elements, classes, and ids.

One approach is to use the additional element `thead` to identify the header row of your table. This is styleable as you're styling the child of `thead` and not the parent of an element.

```css
thead>tr {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another approach is to simply give the row that is the header its own class instead of using `thead`.

Suddenly, this too is styleable. We indicate we are looking for a `tr` (a table row) that ALSO has a class (indicated by the `.` in the CSS below with no space before it) called `header-row`

```css
tr.header-row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="header-row">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As a last resort, (and I would really hope you could avoid this but...) if you're completely stuck with the structure you've shown you could potentially use a sibling selector `~` for the element and its subsequent siblings. It won't apply it to the `tr` parent but it will apply to all the `th` elements. HOWEVER, similar to the "parent" issue you're trying to address this will only work if the "id'd" element is the first element in the row.

```css
#yeah, #yeah ~ th {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th id="yeah">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are not CSS selectors which target a parent from another element. But alternatively, you can colorize all `td` or `th` that is a sibling of the one with given id.

```
#yeah {
  background: red;
}

#yeah ~ th, #yeah ~ td{
  background-color: red
}
```

This will colorize the cell with id=Yeah in red, and its siblings in blue.

But there is a catch: the red cell must be the *first* in the row (as you example table), since the sibling selector "~" only affects the elements *after* the target.